# How is by-id created on Linux?

Tags: linux, dev, id

Sticking a USB-microcontroller on the port (similar to Arduino) creates these two files:

```
/dev/serial/by-id/usb-MBED_MBED_CMSIS-DAP_10105a42e87da33c103dccfb6bc235360a97-if01
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-MBED_microcontrolleur_10105a42e87da33c103dccfb6bc235360a97-0:0
```

Are the ids in this case generated on the fly by a program or are they hardcoded somewhere on the device itself?

If it is created on the fly:

1. How excactly is it created?
2. Will it exist only on Linux machines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file name is generated by udev, but the id inside it comes from the device itself:

if you run `lsusb -v` and search for it, you'll find it's the serial id of the device:

```
...
iManufacturer        MBED
iProduct             microcontrolleur
iSerial              10105a42e87da33c103dccfb6bc235360a97
```

or something similar.

---

How does this happen ?

Let's say the usb stick gets mounted on `/mnt/tmp`. On my system i get:

```
$ udevadm info --device-id-of-file /mnt/tmp
8:17
```

Now run this and search for `8:17`:

```
$ udevadm info --export-db | less
...
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1
N: sdb1
W: 61
S: block/8:17
S: disk/by-id/usb-pqi_IntelligentStick_AA04212900042956-0:0-part1
```

This gives us the device path to use with udevadm. Run this and search for for your device id (`AA042...` in my case)

```
$ udevadm test /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 2>&1 | less
...
udev_rules_apply_to_event: LINK 'disk/by-id/usb-pqi_IntelligentStick_AA04212900042956-0:0-part1' /lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:31
```

That gives us all the udev rules + line numbers applied (`60-persistent-storage.rules:31` etc)

And here's where the file name comes from:

```
$ /lib/udev/usb_id /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb
pqi_IntelligentStick_AA04212900042956-0:0
```

Comment: The question is then how lsusb gets this info.. because it might use `udev` like `udisks` does.

Comment: You can check the serial number really comes from the device itself by running ChipGenius under windows.

Comment: as alex showed, `udev` just concatenates the serial id from the kernel into a larger string. `lsusb` or `lsblk` use the same serial id. there's no treachery going on. feel free to trust built-in `ls` commands; otherwise, what can you trust?

Answer (score 6):

`by-id` symlinks are created by `udev` rules (and are specific to OS'es using `udev`)

You can find the specific rules in `/lib/udev/rules.d`:

for `serial` devices in `60-persistent-serial.rules`:

```
ENV{.ID_PORT}=="", SYMLINK+="serial/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}-if$env{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}"
ENV{.ID_PORT}=="?*", SYMLINK+="serial/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}-if$env{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}-port$env{.ID_PORT}"
```

and for the `disk` devices in `60-persistent-storage.rules`:

```
KERNEL=="sd*|sr*|cciss*", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}"
```